# What can cause a sudden increase in the number of processes at my VPS?

Tags: linux, process, apache-http-server, vps

My VPS (Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS ) dies few times a month. Only restarting whole VPS through hosting panel helps. I discovered that the cause of that is a sudden increase of the number of processes.

I've checked /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log and /var/log/apache2/error.log - nothing special, just a lot of standard errors and these ones:

```
[14/Jan/2014:18:43:34 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

What can cause this huge increase of processes? 
Is there some way or log file for processes to check what processes were running then?

The server is restarted now. So there is drop down in number of processes at the moment, so i can't retrace procesess.

Here are few of Munin charts:
[image: Processes]

[image: Memory Usage]

[image: CPU Usage]

[image: SWAP OUT/IN]

And here is TOP:
[image: TOP procceses now]

Comment: can you ssh into the VPS, then use `top` or `htop` (if installed) command and have a look at the processes. also check whether the system uses swap memory?

Comment: Azker, i've updated my question with command top information and additional swap in out chart.

Comment: You might try enabling process accounting (STFW for details).